# Regular expression to extract string between a word and dot followed by strings

Tags: regex

How can we extract string **1074933442** from :
`sameword-1074933442.bac-de.prod.domain.google.com`.
I am looking for `1074933442` as output.

I tried `sameword-(.*)\.\w+` but it gives me `1074933442.bac-de.prod.domain.google` as output.

Any suggestions?